# Correctness of Strongly Connected Components algorithm for a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

I have been reading up on algorithm for finding the strongly connected components in a directed graph $G=(V,E)$. It considers two DFS search and the second step is transposing the original graph $G^T$.

The algorithm is the following :

1. Execute DFS on $G$ (starting at an arbitrary starting vertex), keeping track of the ﬁnishing times of all vertices.
2. Compute the transpose,
3. Execute DFS on $G^T$, starting at the vertex with the latest ﬁnishing time, forming a tree rooted at that vertex. Once a tree is completed, move on to the unvisited vertex with the next latest ﬁnishing time and form another tree using DFS and repeat until all the vertices in $G^T$ are visited.
4. Output the vertices in each tree formed by the second DFS as a separate strongly connected component.

My question is :

1. What is the intuition behind this middle step of computing a transpose?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Transposing the adjecency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph) $A$ does

$\qquad A[i,j] = 1 \iff A^T[j,i] = 1$.

In terms of graphs, that means

$\qquad u \to_G v \iff v \to_{G^T} u$.

In other words, transposing reverses the direction of all edges. Note that $G^T$ has the same strong components as $G$.

The algorithm you are looking at is [Kosaraju's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm). Be carful with your notion of "finishing time": it's not the time the node is visited, but when the search has traversed the subgraph reachable from it. Wikipedia proposes to use a stack to manage this, which I think is a good idea.

Why is it correct to use $G^T$, intuitively? Assume $x$ is the first node of its strong component visited by the DFS.

- The DFS on $G$ traverses the whole strong component of $x$ after reaching $x$, plus some others via edges that leave the component.
- Since we use a stack order for remembering the order of nodes, $x$ is also the first node of its strong component visited (as starting node, even) in the second phase.
- Since $G$ and $G^T$ have the same strong components, all nodes in the strong component of $x$ are visited when searching $G^T$ from $x$. Those edges leaving the component in the first phase point in the wrong direction in $G^T$ and are thus not followed. All edges leaving the component of $x$ in $G^T$ have already been removed because of the stack order.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding:

When you execute DFS on any DAG graph keeping track of the finishing times, the **only** thing you can guarantee is that **sink node will never get the highest finishing time [1]**. But at the same time, **the lowest finishing time may appear in any component of the graph**. Hence, it makes the lowest finishing time kind of useless.

Basically, the fact **[1]** is useless **in the original graph** as well, but it is very useful **in the transposed graph**. When you transpose, this statement leads to the following:

In the transposed graph, the node that was a sink in the non-transposed graph **will always get the highest finishing time**.

Answer (score 2):

1. strongly connected components in $G$ and $G_{transpose}$ will remain the same (implied by definition of strongly connected components)
2. any graph can be divided into strongly connected components - let's call these components $C_1, C_2, C_3 \dots C_N$

After first round of DFS and sorting in descending order of finish time

Let's say the component $C_i$ has the node with highest finish time.
One tricky thing to observe that this component $C_i$ which has highest finish time
cannot have any outside edge coming into the component $C_i$.

To prove the above fact (by contradiction):-
let's consider that there exists a component $C_j$ from which there is an edge into component $C_i$.
And $C_j$ has no node which has larger finish time than $C_i$'s node -

but this is not possible because during DFS $C_j$ will have then larger finish
time. (Even if you start DFS from any node - you can check by yourself.)

Now you have component $C_i$ and no outside edge is coming inside $C_i$
so if you transpose the graph the components will not change (because strongly connected) but the edges connecting them will be reversed.

Therefore $C_i$ have no edge going out to other components. That's all we wanted;
if you apply DFS on this graph starting from any node of $C_i$ you will traverse only through this $C_i$ component and will not enter into others.

This way you have separated $C_i$ from graph.

Hope that helped,
comment if you have any doubt, I'll try to reply asap

Comment: Good explanation! Your answer is simpler than all the others and I like it very much.